# Sum all elements in a vector except the ith element without for-loop

Tags: r, for-loop, vectorization

As the title says. I have a vector and I want to sum all elements in the vector, except the ith element. I can achieve this with a for-loop e.g.

```
# vector to iterate over
v1 <- 1:5

# somewhere to store results
v2 <- c()

for (i in seq_along(v1)) {
v2[i] <-  sum(v1[-i])  
}

# desired output
v2
[1] 14 13 12 11 10
```

I am looking for performance gains, Is it possible to achieve `v2` without a `for-loop` via vectorisation?

Comment: `sum(v1) - v1`?

Comment: @JonSpring Please submit this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done without a loop using:

```
sum(v1) - v1
```

This will, for all elements of `v1`, provide the sum of all of `v1` excluding that element. Since it's a vectorized approach, it will be faster than a loop. https://www.noamross.net/archives/2014-04-16-vectorization-in-r-why/